# Substitution Cypher

Tags: c++

I have problem with this problem I dont know what should I do my code work truly but I dont know why I get wrong answer I dont when my input should be end until end of file???? can you help me to solve my problem thanks here is the link of question.
http://sharecode.ir/section/problemset/problem/2124.
my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string alfa,alfa2,word;
    cin>>alfa;
    cin>>alfa2;
    cout<<alfa2<<endl;
    cout<<alfa<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    while(getline(cin,word))
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<word.size() ; i++)
        {
            bool cheak =false;
            for(int j=0 ; j<alfa.size() ; j++)
            {
                if(word[i] == alfa[j])
                {
                    printf("%c",alfa2[j]);
                    cheak = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(cheak == false)
                printf("%c",word[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a space character in the two first line of input.

Use this method:

```
string alfa,alfa2,word;

getline(cin, alfa);
getline(cin, alfa2);
cout<<alfa2<<endl;
cout<<alfa<<endl;
```

And drop the `cin.ignore()` in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'error' is the following:

You are outputting the `alpha2` and `alpha` before reading the `text`. You should start your output after finishing reading all the input.

**Note: This is not an error, but the online judge may be rejecting it as it follows a fixed sequence.**

Comment: no I try in this way but I get wrong answer but thank for your attention

Comment: my output in this code is exactly the same with my new code thats the reason I said this not the answer

Comment: @Danial You didn't get my point. The output is the same but in one case you wait for entire file input, in the other you do not. If you show your final updated code as per my answer, then probably things can be seen. Because I don't find any other error here.

Comment: And just one more thing the input file and output file is separated
and don't have any related my output is in output file and is exactly like output that the question said isn't it??

Comment: @Danial I'm suggesting this to you from personal experience :)

Comment: Thank a lot for spending your time I waiting for someone that accepted this question

Comment: @Danial You can post your questions on sharecode's discussions! It will be notify all the people that have that problem accepted about your question :)